# Fast smoothing of scattered data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, smoothing

I am looking for a method in which I can smooth a scattered dataset. The scattered dataset comes from sampling a very large array that represents a raster. I have to vectorize this array in order to downsample it. I have done so using the `matplotlib.pyplot.contour()` function, and I get reasonable set of point value pairs.

The problem is that this signal is noisy, and I need to smooth it. Smoothing the original array is no good, I need to smooth the scattered data. The best I could find is the function below, which I rewrote from a Matlab counterpart. While this function does the job, it is very slow. I am looking either for alternative functions to smooth this data or a way to make the function below faster.

```py
def limgrad(self, triangulation, values, dfdx, imax=100):
    """
    See https://github.com/dengwirda/mesh2d/blob/master/hjac-util/limgrad.m
    for original source code.
    """
    # triangulation is a matplotlib.tri.Triangulation instance
    edge = triangulation.edges
    dx = np.subtract(
        triangulation.x[edge[:, 0]], triangulation.x[edge[:, 1]])
    dy = np.subtract(
        triangulation.y[edge[:, 0]], triangulation.y[edge[:, 1]])
    elen = np.sqrt(dx**2+dy**2)
    aset = np.zeros(values.shape)
    ftol = np.min(values) * np.sqrt(np.finfo(float).eps)
    for i in range(1, imax + 1):
        aidx = np.where(aset == i-1)[0]
        if len(aidx) == 0.:
            break
        active_idxs = np.argsort(values[aidx])
        for active_idx in active_idxs:
            adj_edges_idxs = np.where(
                np.any(edge == active_idx, axis=1))[0]
            adjacent_edges = edge[adj_edges_idxs]
            for nod1, nod2 in adjacent_edges:
                if values[nod1] > values[nod2]:
                    fun1 = values[nod2] + elen[active_idx] * dfdx
                    if values[nod1] > fun1+ftol:
                        values[nod1] = fun1
                        aset[nod1] = i
                else:
                    fun2 = values[nod1] + elen[active_idx] * dfdx
                    if values[nod2] > fun2+ftol:
                        values[nod2] = fun2
                        aset[nod2] = i
    return values
```

Comment: maybe you could have a look at this [scipy tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) to see if there is something useful for you. It is mostly about interpolation but the spline functions can be used also for smoothing.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question and I am posting here for reference. The algorith above is slow because calling np.where() to generate adj_edges_idxs has a heavy overhead. Instead, I precompute the node neighbors and that eliminates the overhead. It went from ~80 iterations per second to 80,000 it/s.

The final version looks like this:

```
def limgrad(tri, values, dfdx=0.2, imax=100):
    """
    See https://github.com/dengwirda/mesh2d/blob/master/hjac-util/limgrad.m
    for original source code.
    """
    xy = np.vstack([tri.x, tri.y]).T
    edge = tri.edges
    dx = np.subtract(xy[edge[:, 0], 0], xy[edge[:, 1], 0])
    dy = np.subtract(xy[edge[:, 0], 1], xy[edge[:, 1], 1])
    elen = np.sqrt(dx**2+dy**2)
    ffun = values.flatten()
    aset = np.zeros(ffun.shape)
    ftol = np.min(ffun) * np.sqrt(np.finfo(float).eps)
    # precompute neighbor table
    point_neighbors = defaultdict(set)
    for simplex in tri.triangles:
        for i, j in permutations(simplex, 2):
            point_neighbors[i].add(j)
    # iterative smoothing
    for _iter in range(1, imax+1):
        aidx = np.where(aset == _iter-1)[0]
        if len(aidx) == 0.:
            break
        active_idxs = np.argsort(ffun[aidx])
        for active_idx in active_idxs:
            adjacent_edges = point_neighbors[active_idx]
            for adj_edge in adjacent_edges:
                if ffun[adj_edge] > ffun[active_idx]:
                    fun1 = ffun[active_idx] + elen[active_idx] * dfdx
                    if ffun[adj_edge] > fun1+ftol:
                        ffun[adj_edge] = fun1
                        aset[adj_edge] = _iter
                else:
                    fun2 = ffun[adj_edge] + elen[active_idx] * dfdx
                    if ffun[active_idx] > fun2+ftol:
                        ffun[active_idx] = fun2
                        aset[active_idx] = _iter
    flag = _iter < imax
    return ffun, flag
```